# Who was a Roman General for a short time?

Tags: europe, roman-empire, battle, ancient-rome

I'm trying to remember the name and battle that a Roman General. I might be unintentionally mixing parts of it up with other historic parts. The story goes the Roman Empire need someone to lead their armies for a battle; they drafted this "farmer" from their own territories. This "farmer" lead the armies to victory and was sent back home within two weeks.

Comment: Are you sure this is historical and not fiction?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the story of Cincinnatus.

Answer (score 3):

Probably we're talking about [Cincinnatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_Quinctius_Cincinnatus).

Comment: Link only answer? The story is what? I mean Lucius was a patrician, so no "ordinary farmer". Please expand on this to explain how he might fit the description.

Comment: While you are probably right, note that various things do not match up (probably due to misremembering) this should be mentioned.